# Can Social Engine, Elgg, or PHPFox work in this fassion?

Tags: elgg, socialengine, phpfox

I would like to build a SaaS that performs like the following and I am checking out Elgg,SocialEngine, and PHPFox to see if any of these fit the bill.

- I would like to keep the site private (no public info shown)
- Organizations can signup (administer of org is charged)
- Orgs have members who dont pay subscription fee
- Orgs can have sub-groups/communities that are viewable within the org but not viewable to other orgs or if private
- Orgs cannot see other orgs or content of other orgs
- features of orgs allows communications with groups, event planning, shared docs, social integration, etc

Can any php or maybe rails based software do this without heavy modification?

Answer (score 1):

Elgg can do this, but it would require a fair bit of coding - not so much for the multi-site part, there's a plugin for that, but just to customize the site.  For example, if you want to have a fully featured "event planning" page, you'd probably have to write that...but I'd guess that this would be the case with pretty much any framework.

Comment: +1 for Elgg. 
Advantages : No need of any commercial license, all your needs can be implemented in it, though needs some development.

Answer (score 0):

SocialEngine could do this however every organization would need its own license and working copy of SocialEngine unless you were to customize your version of SocialEngine to handle these organizations and their privacies and abilities. If you purchase your own copy of SocialEngine, all source code is available to you and you are free to customize the code to create the site that best suits your needs as you deem fit.